# How to keep the rows contain same value of a specific column between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Say,I have two tables T1 and T2(in sql). I only want to keep the rows in T1 which have same value of a column between these tables. How should I do it!?

[image: Please have a look]

Here T1.Status and T2.Status contain the same value and I would like to keep  only these two rows in T1 deleting other ones from T1. How will it be possible(faster in query because there will be a thousands of rows)!?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `IN`.  `EXISTS`.  These all come to mind.

Comment: Please explain a bit.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html is what you're likely looking for. This is how you can combine tables together. What SQL have you tried so far?  I believe `SELECT T1.* FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T2.name = T1.name AND T2.status = T1.status` should get you close.

Comment: Do you want to actually `DELETE` those rows, so they're permanently removed from the table, forever.  Or, just join the tables together and "ignore" the rows where the status doesn't match?  *(Is this a data retrieval question, or a data modification question?)*

Comment: Yes, they will be permanently deleted from the table. It is a question of data modification :( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery can be used to check, if no matching record exists.

```
DELETE FROM t1
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM t2
                                     WHERE t2.name = t1.name
                                           AND t2.status = t1.status);
```

Comment: Thank you,
First I did - 
<br>
$query2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT t1.*
    FROM t1
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                         FROM t2
                         WHERE t1.Status = t2.Status)");
echo '<br><br>';
while ($row = $query2->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo 'Name: '.$row['Name'].' Status: '.$row['Status'].'<br>';
}
<br>
it showed my desire ..... Now with your code it's working. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my sample create queries:

```
CREATE TABLE `T1` (
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `id` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `status` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`));

INSERT INTO T1 (name, id, status) VALUES
('x1', 1, 1),
('x2', 2, 1),
('x3', 3, 1),
('x4', 4, 1);

CREATE TABLE `T2` (
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `status` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`));

INSERT INTO T2 (name, email, status) VALUES
('x1', 'a', 1),
('x2', 'b', 1),
('x3', 'c', 3),
('x4', 'd', 4);
```

Then you want to select all rows from `T1` where the name and status are the same as in `T2`:

```
SELECT
    1.*
FROM
    T1
    JOIN T2 ON T2.name = T1.name AND T2.status = T1.status;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot but I can not use name(AccountEmail in real table) as the PRIMARY KEY, as UserID is already using as PRIMARY KEY in real table on which I am working on.
I need to change the stored data ot T1 table as of the above image.
The last T1 table should only have the rows which matches the Status of T2 :( .

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you wanted things actually deleted. My recommendation then is to create a temporary table with the final schema you want, then select the data from T1 and insert it into your temp table. Then delete T1 and rename your temp table to T1.

Comment: Nice idea- it will keep a backup, Thank you.